# SQL Trigger on Insert, Delete, Updated

Tags: sql, t-sql, triggers

I have the following trigger

```
 ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[RefreshProject]
   ON  [dbo].[Project] 
   AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @percentage decimal(18,2)
DECLARE @ProjectID int
DECLARE @TASKID int

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Inserted)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @ProjectID = Inserted.ProjectID, @TASKID = ISNULL(Inserted.TASKID,-1) from Inserted join Project on Inserted.ScheduleID = Project.ScheduleID
    END

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Deleted)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @ProjectID = Deleted.ProjectID,@TASKID = ISNULL(Deleted.TASKID,-1) from Deleted join Project on Deleted.ScheduleID = Project.ScheduleID
    END

    BEGIN
         SET @percentage = (SELECT percentage from Project where ProjectID = @ProjectID)
         EXEC LoadSummary @percentage,@ProjectID, @TASKID
    END
END
```

For Inserts and updates I am able to get the ProjectID of the modified object, however when an item is deleted, I can not get the ProjectID or TaskID... Any Idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: your trigger doesn't deal with multiple rows...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your trigger is an `AFTER` trigger, which means that the row has already been deleted from the `Project` table by the time the trigger is fired. So, you can't join the `deleted` view to `Project`, because the corresponding row won't exist. You will need to assign the variables you want directly from the `deleted` view.

Also, as Mitch's note mentions above, you may want to use a cursor to iterate over all rows in the `inserted`/`deleted` views if multiple rows can be updated at a time. Alternatively, you could raise an error at the beginning of your trigger if `@@ROWCOUNT` is greater than one, to prevent multiple row updates from causing your trigger to misbehave.

Comment: You should **NEVER EVER** use a **CURSOR** inside a trigger!! Yes, you need to handle multiple rows in the `Inserted` and `Deleted` pseudo-tables - but **PLEEEEEEAAAAASSSSEEEEEEEEE** not with a cursor!